# Finding 10,000th smallest number in the series (3^i * 5^j * 7^k) where i,j,k >= 0 using data structures

Tags: data-structures

How can I solve the following problem using Data Structures?

3^i * 5^J * 7^k where i,j,k >=0. find the 10, 000th smallest number in this series.

I solved it using sets in the following way, which I feel is not an efficient solution:

- initial set is (1)
- multiply each element of the set by numbers 3,5 and 7 to get the next set.
- take a union with previous set.
- if the size of set is greater than or equal to 10,000, stop the process of multiplication and sort the set in ascending order.
- 10,000th element of the set will be the 10,000th smallest number.

Is there any other data structure which can solve this problem more efficiently?

Comment: This is the same problem as generating "Hamming Numbers" [see code here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Hamming_numbers#Python)

Comment: +1 for the link. I like Python, but why point specifically at the Python implementation in the middle of the page (and not the easiest implementation to understand)? [Here is the "language agnostic" link](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Hamming_numbers) ;-)